# Iteration of map from db and getting the common elements

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a dbmap which holds the database data

```
List<Long,List<validitycommerce>> dbmap= new HashMap<Long,List<ValidityCommerceregion>>

ValidityCommerceRegion contains 

Validity id,
commerce id,
region id,
```

Now I have incoming list coming commerce id and region id say 151 be and 17 lu and I found the validityid of both 151 and 17 and I got the list of validityid's

Now I want to find the common validityid in both 151 BE and 17 LU

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify `Now i have incoming list coming commerce id and region id say 151 be and 17 lu and i found the validityid of both 151 and 17 and i got the list of validityid's`

Comment: i am getting 151 BE and 17 LU as input now i want to find the common validityids between both

Comment: What are 151 BE, 17 LU ? what are validity IDs ?